# Password field default value

Tags: javascript, html

How can I both use the HTML password input and set a text default value that will be readable since the password input will turn the characters into dots or stars?  Can I do this with Javascript?

Comment: Please tell, why do you want your password field to be readable ?

Comment: do you know of someone that doesn't know what a password field is? What ever happened to using a `label`?

Comment: possible duplicate of the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660237/default-value-password-for-input-field-show-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want it to read "password" or whatever in regular letters until someone clicks on it, at which point it will turn blank, and anything typed in there will become *'s? Ok what you want is this:

in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changefield(){
        document.getElementById("passwordbox").innerHTML = "<input id=\"password-field\" type=\"password\" name=\"password-field\" title=\"Password\" />";
        document.getElementById("password-field").focus();
    }
</script>
```

in the body:

```
<div id="passwordbox">
<input id="password-field" type="text" name="password-field" title="Password" onfocus="changefield();" value="password" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect.  Just for other users, there's a ) missing before the focus().

Comment: My bad, fixed bracket in my answer

Comment: If you use a password manager it won't work. See my comment below for more info.

Answer (score 2):

In head:

```
    function Changetxt() {
        if ($('#pwd').val() == "Enter Your Password Here") {
            $('#pwd').val('');
            $('#pwd').css('color', 'black');
        }
    }

    function textboxtype() {
        if ($('#pwd').val().length < 1) {
            $('#pwd').val('Enter Your Password Here');
            $('#pwd').css('color', 'gray');
        }
    }
```

In body:

```
<input type="text" id="pwd" style="width: 180px; color: Gray;" onfocus="Changetxt();this.type='password'"
                            onblur="if(this.value==''){this.type='text';textboxtype();}" value="Enter Your Password Here" />
```

Comment: <input type="text" id="pwd" style="width: 180px; color: Gray;" onfocus="Changetxt();this.type='password'"
                                onblur="if(this.value==''){this.type='text';textboxtype();}" value="Enter Your Password Here" />

Comment: I know this thread is old but I want to tell you guys that this code doesn't work if you're using PASSWORD MANAGERS. Why? Because password managers look for a PASSWORD-FIELD (and you set 'type' to 'text'). So you have to log in manually and this sucks BIG TIME! Also it doesn't work for <IE9 because modifying 'type' via JS is not supported by older browsers!

Answer (score 2):

Much easier option using ONLY HTML:

Add this code:

`onfocus="this.value='', this.type='password'"`

to the **input field** and make sure the `type` is initially set to `text`

Example:

```
input onfocus="this.value='', this.type='password'" value="Password" type="text" title="Password" id="password_field" name="signin_password"
```

Comment: "using ONLY HTML" - This is actually JavaScript. But embedded _inline_ in the HTML, which is generally considered bad. Separation of concerns - separation of content and behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript it will sure help you...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Watermark Textbox for Password Textbox Using JavaScript</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function WaterMark(objtxt, event) {
var defaultText = "Enter Username Here";
var defaultpwdText = "Enter Password Here";
// Condition to check textbox length and event type
if (objtxt.id == "txtUserName" || objtxt.id == "txtPwd") {
if (objtxt.value.length == 0 & event.type == "blur") {
//if condition true then setting text color and default text in textbox
if (objtxt.id == "txtUserName") {
objtxt.style.color = "Gray";
objtxt.value = defaultText;
}
if (objtxt.id == "txtPwd") {
document.getElementById("<%= txtTempPwd.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
objtxt.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
// Condition to check textbox value and event type
if ((objtxt.value == defaultText || objtxt.value == defaultpwdText) & event.type == "focus") {
if (objtxt.id == "txtUserName") {
objtxt.style.color = "black";
objtxt.value = "";
}
if (objtxt.id == "txtTempPwd") {
objtxt.style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("<%= txtPwd.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("<%= txtPwd.ClientID %>").focus();
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>UserName:</b></td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text="Enter Username Here" Width="150px" ForeColor="Gray" onblur = "WaterMark(this, event);" onfocus = "WaterMark(this, event);" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Password:</b></td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTempPwd" Text="Enter Password Here" runat="server" onfocus="WaterMark(this, event);" Width="150px" ForeColor="Gray" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" TextMode="Password" Text="Enter Password Here" runat="server" Width="150px" Style="display:none" onblur="WaterMark(this, event);"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input type="password" value="" placeholder="Insert your password..."/>
```

This way, as soon as the user starts typing, the suggestion would go automatically away.

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="password" name="x" id="x" value="some value" onclick="alert(this.value);" />
```

Answer (score -2):

if you do this the field text is readable just like username..  why such a question?

```
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" />
```