# Display default value in password field as plaintext

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to display the default text in a password field as plaintext ?

Using below code the textfield value is displayed as "********" instead of "Password"

Thanks

```
<div id="fnameDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">    
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="Password"/>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password field default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786035/password-field-default-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t4BQm/18/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="jqm-home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="fnameDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">  
            <label for="name">Password:</label>  
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <div id="fnameDivHidden" class="hidden_div" data-role="fieldcontain">  
            <label for="name">Password:</label>  
            <input id="password_hidden" name="password_hidden" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <legend>Display Password:</legend>
                     <input type="radio" name="show_password" id="no" value="no" checked="checked" />
                     <label for="no">No</label>

                     <input type="radio" name="show_password" id="yes" value="yes" />
                     <label for="yes">Yes</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('[name=show_password]').change(function() {
    var show = $('input[name=show_password]:checked').val() == 'yes';

    // toggle the password and the hidden text inputs
    $('#password_hidden').val($('#password').val());

    if(show) {
        $('#fnameDivHidden').show();
        $('#fnameDiv').hide();
    } else {
        $('#fnameDivHidden').hide();
        $('#fnameDiv').show();
    }
});

$('#fnameDivHidden').hide();
```

This might be Related: [change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

Comment: In the end this is all I needed - <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/> Thanks

Comment: placeholder is a HTML5 attribute, so if you need something like this for older script I think jQuery offers a plugin that does this as well

Comment: Seems HTML5 is supported by webkit mobile browsers? If so, it should be fine for my needs