# default value 'password' for input field, show it?

Tags: javascript, input

I'm using this js to display default password, when user clicks it automatically clears default value, if user deselects without entering anything default value re-appears.

I used it for all my fields, but obviously for password it is trickier! :)

How would you do it?

```
<input
    type="password"
    onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Password':this.value;"
    onfocus="this.select()"
    onclick="if (this.value=='Password'){this.value='';}"
    name="pwd"
    id="user_pass"
    class="input"
    value="Password"
    size="20"
    tabindex="20" />
```

Comment: You want this default value to be visible but then if they type something else show *****?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cgP5K/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cgP5K/1/

```
<input
  type="text"
  onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Password':this.value;"
  onfocus="this.select()"
  onclick="if (this.value=='Password'){this.value=''; this.type='password'}"
  name="pwd"
  id="user_pass"
  class="input"
  value="Password"
  size="20"
  tabindex="20" />​
```

Comment: Keep in mind this won't work if you click the field and then click away without typing anything it will switch to be bullets and you can't change the type of an input twice with Javascript.  To fix that you need to use the placeholder method.

Comment: @Rob Lowe - I'll give you a +1 if you put the code in your answer.

Comment: I don't understand why the onblur event works. Shouldn't it be `this.value!=this.defaultValue`?

Answer (score 3):

Were you thinking of `<input placeholder='Password' type='password'/>` ?

Comment: That's the correct solution, but doesn't really tell the OP much about why. I'd have given you +1 if you'd take the time to explain what `placeholder` is; that it's HTML5 standard for doing what that question is asking, and that it doesn't work on older browsers so might need a polyfill script.

Comment: Admittedly I was terse, but doesn't `placeholder` describe itself? Agreed that `placeholder` is not as widely supported, but a browser target is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try This out - http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/text-in-password/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a plain text input as a placeholder.  This code will do that for you without exposing any variables to the global scope:

```
​<input id="pass-placeholder" type="text"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ value="Password" />
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var pass_holder_el = document.getElementById('pass-placeholder');
    var pass_el = document.createElement('input');
    pass_el.type = 'password';

    pass_el.onblur = function(){
        if(!this.value)
            this.parentNode.replaceChild(pass_holder_el, this);
    }

    pass_holder_el.onfocus = function(){
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(pass_el, this);
        pass_el.focus();    
    }
})();
</script>​
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RTyF/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below solution,

```
<input name="password" class="input"value="Password" size="20"
  tabindex="20"  onclick="if(this.value==defaultValue){this.value=''; this.type='password'} else if(this.value==''){this.value=defaultValue; this.type='text'} " onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=defaultValue; this.type='text'}"/>
```

because first solution works well but if u empty the password field, it will not convert to its default value which is a text. So try above solution.