# How do you make a prompt display what you are typing as dots

Tags: javascript, html

I have recently started making a webpage and I would like some parts of it to be password protected. So I made some parts of it password protected. Now I would like my password not to be shown when I am typing it how would I do that in a javascript prompt?

Comment: If i understand, this link is gonna help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786035/password-field-default-value

Comment: How did you make it password protected?

Comment: Almost but not quite. That link shows how to do it in a input-box but i want to do it in a javascript prompt.

Comment: This is my code for the password: var password = prompt("Please enter password.");
if (password === "Your-Password") {
alert("Correct");
}else{
alert("Incorrect");
self.close();
}

Comment: @DovidSchack You can't mask characters typed into a window prompt. You will have to use a password input field.

Comment: ...and to make matters worse, anyone can just click view source on the page and see what the password is to get into the "protected" area with the `prompt()` method.

Comment: No they can't. It self-closes if you get the password wrong and you can't inspect element while you have a prompt open.

Comment: @DovidSchack — It isn't hard to turn off JS to stop the prompt appearing in the first place.

Comment: @DovidSchack sure you can. There are several ways to get to the password. Please **always** use a serverside script to prevent access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't , prompts do not support this feature, you can look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp).

However you could use Jquery or build your own modal/ dialog to emulate this functionality.

See the jQuery UI [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for ideas and examples.

Answer (score -1):

Modern browsers (including IE10) allow for [creating modals with custom content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html#dialogs-implemented-using-separate-documents), so you can use that.

As for storing the password: while it's better to have it verified by an external server, in case of an offline application, it's quite OK to store it in the script/localStorage as long as it's properly hashed, so that retrieving it in plain text is time-consuming.